# Using Vuetify's v-autocomplete with virtual scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization

I have case where I need to render a table with thousand of rows where each row contains Vuetify's autocomplete component and vuetify checkbox (as well as a couple of plain text columns).

First and obvious solution was to use Vuetify's v-data-table, but you can imagine how the performance was. It took ~10 seconds to render the table initially and ~5 sec to update (if user clicked sort or typed something in search input).

We decided to write our own table using CSS grid and, for optimization purposes, I added [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller), and it helped a lot. I use dynamic version of it since rows can differ in content and height and this makes things a little bit slower, but the main problem is still with Vuetify's components (Autocomplete mostly, disabling it solves the problem).

The only thing a have no idea how to fix is the slow render of Autocomplete component. Virtual scroller works that way that it renders something if it is in viewport, so on scroll rows have to be rendered over and over again and it provoke this junky behavior:
[image]

In ~0.5 seconds the empty space will be filled with rows, but it is more than enough time to confuse and dissapoint users. If I remove Autocomplete, the problem will not be present anymore, so the problem is clearly with it.

I wonder if it is possible to lazy render components somehow.

Would be glad to hear any advise. If the problem is unclear, please let me know and I will try to provide demo, but it will take some time since our sources are private.